# How to run a single phpUnit test in a separate process?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Is it possible to run a test suite of phpUnit tests in the same process, but identify specific tests to be run in their own processes?

Normally I use

```
@runTestsInSeparateProcesses
@preserveGlobalState disabled
```

for an entire test suite, but I only need a single method to be ran separately, and I'd like the speed increase of having the rest run in a single process.

Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As you can see in [PHPUnit manual](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.runInSeparateProcess) you can use the `@runInSeparateProcess` tag:

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
    * @runInSeparateProcess
    */
    public function testInSeparateProcess()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Implementing that function with a simple `echo "working?";` causes my phpUnit test suite to 'hang' and never finish executing.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You mean using the docblock?

Comment: Using the docblock causes my function in my test suite to hang, but not when I run a script with the basic shell you have above.  It seems I may have a issue because I'm extending PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase through an abstract class which I'm inheriting from.

Comment: I've also experienced that hanging. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: This is for one test. If you want for all, use `--process-isolation` as parameter